# Elitism is failing in Genetic Algorithm

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm

I am trying to run a genetic algorithm that i wrote in python. Unfortunately when there is a mutation the fittest solution can be worse that the fittest solution of the previous generation despite using elitism to pass the fittest solution from the previous generation to the new one. Like so:

```
There are 86825 generations left
Invalid count is:  0
The fittest individual has a fitness of 16.9094. 
The least fit individual has a fitness  of 36.6535
*******************************************************************************
mutation on 107
There are 86824 generations left
Invalid count is:  3
The fittest individual has a fitness of 19.8637. 
The least fit individual has a fitness of 1.1618e+09
```

I have tried to implement elitism which I thought would avoid this happening but it still happens. My algorithm executes in this order:

```
NUM_GEN = 100000
print "Running Genetic Algorithm for %d generations." % NUM_GEN
gen_count = 0
while gen_count < NUM_GEN:
    #genetic.add_fitness_key()
    genetic.add_fitness_fast()
    fittest_list = np.append(fittest_list, genetic.fittest_fitness)
    least_fit_list = np.append(least_fit_list, genetic.least_fitness)
    genetic.sort_pop()
    genetic.make_new_pop()
    genetic.elitism()
    genetic.population = genetic.new_pop
    print "There are %g generations left" %(NUM_GEN-gen_count) 
    gen_count+=1
```

And the functions that are called are these:

```
def select_parent_from_tournament(self):
    x = random.randint(0, 19)
    player1 = self.population[x]
    y = random.randint(0, 19)
    player2 = self.population[y]
    if player1['fitness'] <= player2['fitness']:
        parent = player1['chrom_list']
    else:
        parent = player2['chrom_list']
    return parent

def crossover(self):
    crossover_point = random.randint(0, self.chromosome_size)*(self.string_length)
    parent1 = self.select_parent_from_tournament()
    parent2 = self.select_parent_from_tournament()
    parent1 = self.mutate(parent1)
    parent2 = self.mutate(parent2)
    child1 = parent1[:crossover_point] + parent2[crossover_point:]
    child2 = parent1[crossover_point:] + parent2[:crossover_point]
    return child1, child2

def mutate(self, chromosome):
    for i in range(len(chromosome)):
        if random.random() < self.mutation_rate:
            print 'mutation on %i' % i
            if chromosome[i] =='0':
                chromosome[i] = '1'
            else:
                chromosome[i] = '0'
    return chromosome

def make_new_pop(self):
    self.new_pop = []
    for i in range(10):
        dictionary1= {}
        dictionary2 = {}
        dictionary1['chrom_list'], dictionary2['chrom_list'] = \
        self.crossover()
        self.new_pop = np.append(self.new_pop, [dictionary1, dictionary2])

def elitism(self):
    r = random.randint(0, 19)
    self.new_pop[r] = self.population[0]
```

So I can't understand why the fittest solution from the old population isn't passed to the new population if there is a mutation?

Comment: Have you done any debugging?

Comment: There might be a chance that your fittest individual gets destroyed after crossover/mutation..?

Comment: @equinoxel @frb If I `print genetic.population` out before or after `genetic.elitism()` in my while loop it prints the solutions with the fittest first. Also if I print`self.population[0]` in the elitism function before `self.new_pop[r] = self.population[0]` it prints the fittest solution.

Comment: @nicholaschris It looks to me that mutation doesn't create a new chromosome, but it modifies the original one. If that's the fittest one, then...

Comment: @euqinoxel: you seems write should chromosome = list(chromosome) at the top of mutate function

Comment: @equinoxel I see what you are saying. But... `parent1` is a **copy(or is this where I am making a mistake and its not a copy but it takes the actual object)** of the best solution between two randomly selected solutions in `genetic.population` from the tournament selection... The copy is modified but the original `genetic.population[0]` should stay the same?

Comment: @Xavier Combelle: As far as I can tell, chromosome is already a list but I may have not made that clear by excluding some of the code.Or is there another reason I should write `list=list(chromosome)`? Thanks

Comment: @equinoxel and Xavier Combelle: Thanks guys I think I've got it! I learnt a valuable lesson today!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your crossover method, you perform the `parent1 = self.select_parent_from_tournament()` which returns the reference to the list of a chromosome from the original population. After that, you do a mutation which modifies the list (in the original population). Only after mutation you copy the content in a child via `child1 = parent1[:crossover_point] + parent2[crossover_point:]`. As @Xavier was suggesting, you need to create a physical copy of your element from the original population in `mutation()`.

In effect, your `mutation()` method changed the original population.

As a side note, generally crossover and mutation are two different operations. Also, there are references in the literature suggesting that mutation probability should be kept very low. Otherwise it will keep you from converging.

Comment: Thank you! I added `chromosome = list(chromosome)` directly below `def mutate(self, chromosome)`. It works. I obviously need to learn more about how python references objects!

Comment: @nicholaschris no worries :) I had the same problems few years back.